# Fixed camera rotate to follow character

Tags: 3d, camera, ios, scenekit

I have  a camera in a fixed position in the middle of a field, and I would like to rotate the camera to follow the character as it moves around. There is no point lower than the camera, but I would like it to follow vertically as well. Given the point/euler angle of the camera, and the point of the character, what math could I use to implement this?

Comment: Should the camera follow the character or is the position fixed and it should only rotate to face the character?

Comment: It should only rotate to face the character. Sorry if my English was unclear.

Comment: Have you tried adding a constraint to the camera node using SCNLookAtConstraint(target: SCNNode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*<sub>(Since the question states only one angle this answer assumes rotation on one axis in 3D-space)</sub>*

Given these inputs on a y-up coordinate system:

```
cameraPos    = (cx, cy, cz)
currentAngle = θ
playerPos    = (px, py, pz)
```

We can first calculate the vector pointing from the camera to the player position:

```
playerCamVector = playerPos.xz - cameraPos.xz = (px - cx, pz - cz)
```

We can then calculate the angle of this vector using `atan` (a.k.a. arc tan or tan<sup>-1</sup>):

```
playerCamAngle = atan(playerCamVector.y, playerCamVector.x)
```

We now calculate the difference between this angle and the current camera angle:

```
angleChange = playerCamAngle - currentAngle
```

Given this difference we can now rotate the camera by this much so we face the player:

```
// Rotate on the Y-vector (up)
camera.rotate(Vector.Y, angleChange)
```

If you want smoother movement you should probably use some sort of interpolation to gradually change the camera's rotation instead of instantly moving it.

---

A more compact version would be to just calculate the angle directly:

```
angle = atan(pz - cz, pz - cx)
angleChange = angle - currentAngle
camera.rotate(Vector.Y, delta)
```

Comment: I am rotating on two axis, but I was able to solve it without too much extra work due to this answer. Thank you.